# Error con método PivotCaches()

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017, interop

Estoy intentando crear tablas dinámicas usando C# y he visto en varios enlaces de internet, como **[este](https://miracle00.weebly.com/excel-cvbnet/easy-way-to-create-excel-pivot-table-with-c-vbnet)** que usan el método `PivotCaches.Add()` para **pasarle como argumento** el **referente a los rangos donde se encuentran los datos.**

El problema es que cuando lo intento usar me da este error, y no sé por qué puede ser.

> **'_Workbook.PivotCaches()' es método, que no es válida en el contexto indicado.**

Al principio pensé que tal vez era algo que estaba mal escrito y pasaba un poco, pero al ver que en varias fuentes utilizan esta forma de pasar los datos, he descartado la idea de que estuviera mal en tantos sitios.

**¿Alguna idea de por qué?**

El IDE que estoy usando es Visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es analizar el enlace que pones en tu pregunta. En el se especifica claramente que está usando una librería externa, *Spire.XLS*

Por otro lado[Workbook.PivotCaches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.pivotcaches.aspx) es efectivamente un método que devuelve una colección `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCaches` **read-only**, con lo que efectivamente no puedes llamar al método `Add` en ella.

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir un `PivotCache` dentro de la colección `PivotCaches` de `Sheet`, no `WorkBook`, de la siguiente manera:

```
PivotCache cache = workbook.Sheets[0].PivotCaches.Add(dataRange);
```